# Hive Partition with NULL

Tags: null, hive

When I try to insert overwrite into hive table B from another table A, i see that there is one extra partition created with NULL value for table B. the source in table A is dynamically partitioned.
I get the like below

```
partition (ds=2015-08-21, source=null)
Loading partition {ds=2015-08-21, source=xxxxx}
Loading partition {ds=2015-08-21, source=xxxxx}
```

It should be not created like partition (ds=2015-08-21, source=null). There is no records in the with source as null in the original table.
But when I look at the table partitions, it shows only the two valid partitions.

```
ds=2015-08-21, source=xxxxx
ds=2015-08-21, source=xxxxx
```

Again, When I try to insert into another table C from table B (inserted above). it gives "**FAILED: NullPointerException null**" error.
Please help
Here the query:

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
                   PARTITION (ds='${date_string}',source)
  SELECT
    f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8
    latest_item.source AS source
  FROM (
    SELECT
     f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,
      top.col6 AS source
    FROM (
      SELECT
        customer_id,
        item_id,
        greatest_n(1, visit_date, order_nbr, base_item_id, cat, subcat, source) top_n
      FROM BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
      WHERE visit_date >= '${ds_window}'
        AND visit_date <= '${date_string}'
        AND source IS NOT NULL
        AND source != ''
      GROUP BY customer_id, item_id
    ) top_ns
    LATERAL VIEW explode(top_n) t AS top
  ) latest_item
  WHERE latest_item.customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND latest_item.customer_id != ''
    AND latest_item.item_id IS NOT NULL
    AND latest_item.item_id != ''
    AND latest_item.days_since_last_purchase > 0
    AND latest_item.subcat IS NOT NULL
    AND latest_item.subcat != ''
    AND latest_item.source != ''
    AND latest_item.source IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Just note: NullPointerException null error is not the full error, so please share the full error log will be great to find the root cause. also do check if the same is causing due to  NULL, then add one condition check to handle the NULL Values, Some Links are already available in Stack overflow it self.

Comment: Hi Deb, Thanks for replying quickly. I dont get any other error. When I try load it is how it looks. "Loading data to table AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA partition (ds=2015-08-22, source=null)
        Loading partition {ds=2015-08-22, source=XXXXX}
        Loading partition {ds=2015-08-22, source=YYYYYY}" . Then when I try to load from this table to another table, thats where i get an error

Comment: I am checking for the source filed to be NOT NULL as well.